# Camera preview stretched after accepting granular permission

Tags: android, surfaceview, camera2

I have created a Camera App that uses both Camera and Camera2 API's. The problem comes when using Camera2 and Granular Permissions.

The App normally starts fine and the preview looks great. But only on the first launch, when the user accepts the Camera and Storage permission, the Camera preview you see is stretched.

NOTE: On lower API Level devices (API 16 - API 22) which don't use granular permissions, the preview is always correct!

Here are some screenshots to see it by yourself:

*Stretched preview*
[image: Stretched]

*Normal preview*
[image: Normal]

My app is OpenSource and available on GitHub. These are some of the classes that may be causing the problem:

[CameraSourcePreview.java](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision/blob/master/Camera2/app/src/main/java/com/example/ezequiel/camera2/others/CameraSourcePreview.java)

[AutoFitTextureView.java](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision/blob/master/Camera2/app/src/main/java/com/example/ezequiel/camera2/others/AutoFitTextureView.java)

[Camera2Source.java](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision/blob/master/Camera2/app/src/main/java/com/example/ezequiel/camera2/others/Camera2Source.java)

Comment: it will be great if you post code regarding camera preview size..

Comment: It is approximately 2K lines of code... too large to put in the question body. That's why I provided three links to the most important classes.

Comment: @EzequielAdrian I'm having the same issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

If you only want to display those images, you can try dependencies like "Picasso" or "Glide". Those two will help you adjust size, scale type etc at the run time. You can easily configure both of them and they'll not let those images stretch.

Comment: It is not a static image and it is not a video. It is a live camera preview.